# Rspec. Delete action doesn't work with let()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I have Rspec testing controller actions via visiting pages.
And when I'm declaring new object through let() for `create` and `edit` actions  - it's all fine. But for `delete` it doesn't work and I have to declare instance variable to make it pass.

**My goal is to get rid of instance variable declaration in delete action.**

It stops me from finishing re-factoring and I want to know why this happen?
Maybe it's somehow related to Capybara scope.

Failed tests looks like:

```
Failure/Error: it {should have_content('delete')}
       expected #has_content?("delete") to return true, got false
```

and

```
Failure/Error: expect{click_link('delete')}.to change(Crew, :count).by(-1)
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "delete"
```

My whole test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'CrewPage' do
  subject {page}

  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  let(:crew) {Crew.create(name: name, secondname: secondname, rate: rate)}
  let(:name) {'Name'}
  let(:secondname) {'First'}
  let(:rate) {1000}

  before {sign_in(user)}
  #==============================New page===========>>
  describe 'new crew member page' do
    before {visit new_crew_path}

    it {should have_title('New member')}

    let(:submit) {"Create"}

    context 'invalid creation' do
      it 'should not create crew member' do
        expect{click_button submit}.not_to change(Crew, :count)
      end
    end

    context 'valid crew member creation' do
      before do
        fill_in 'Name',               with: name
        fill_in 'Secondname',         with: secondname
        fill_in 'Rate',               with: rate
      end
      it 'should create crew member' do
        expect{click_button submit}.to change(Crew, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end

  #==============================Show page===========>>
  describe 'show page' do
    before {visit crew_path(crew)}

    it {should have_title("#{crew.combine_names} profile")}
  end

  #==============================Edit page===========>>
  describe 'edit page' do

    let(:reload_n) {name*2}
    let(:reload_sn) {secondname*2}
    let(:reload_r) {rate*2}

    before {visit edit_crew_path(crew)}

    it {should have_title('Edit panel')}

    context 'successfull edit' do
        before do
        fill_in 'Name',               with: reload_n
        fill_in 'Secondname',         with: reload_sn
        fill_in 'Rate',               with: reload_r
        click_button('Save')
      end
      it {should have_content(reload_n)}
      it {should have_content(reload_sn)}
      it {should have_content(reload_r)}
    end
  end

  #==============================Delete action===========>>
    describe 'delete action from index page' do
        before do
            @crew = Crew.create(name: name, secondname: secondname, rate: rate)
            visit root_path
        end

        it {should have_content('delete')}
        it 'should delete crew member' do
            expect{click_link('delete')}.to change(Crew, :count).by(-1)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` block is not executed unless it is called in the test itself. Because you are not using this variable prior to `visit_page`, crew model is not created and hence it is not displayed on the page capybara is playing with. If you want it to execute before each test, you have to call `let!` instead:

```
let!(:crew) { Crew.create(name: name, secondname: secondname, rate: rate)}
```

Comment: Calling `crew` should work as well: `before { crew; visit root_path }`

Comment: @Stefan, that works fine. Both. But Broi's a bit cleaner. Thanks)